# How to make chained firebase queries asynchronous

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I'm new to web development and things like asynchronicity and promises aren't very clear to me yet so maybe this question might seem a little basic.

Basically I need to fetch the details of a "lesson". In the lesson details is a list of ids which will need to be fetched from another collection. As fire base doesn't support WHERE IN queries I am looping over the values one by one, running the query and appending the result to an array.

I have one query to fetch "lesson" details and another query to fetch a list of "words" by id, both of these queries are called sequentially from a third function and i've made them all synchronous because otherwise I get an error that word_ids (in getWordsById) is undefined (as it has no value until the promise from the query before resolves).

Is there a way to do this asyncronously so I don't have to chain synchronous queries ? I feel like I am missing some understanding of how promises work

```
async getWordsById(word_ids) {
      var words = []
      var arrayLength = word_ids.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        await this.db.collection('words_2').doc(word_ids[i])
          .get().then(function(snap) {words.push(snap.data())})
      }  
      //console.log("Words In Func: ", words)
      return words
  }

  async getPractice (lessonId) {
      var practice_details;
      await this.db.collection('practice').doc(lessonId)
       .get().then(snap => {practice_details = snap.data(); return practice_details;})
       //console.log("Out: ", practice_details)
      return practice_details;

  }

  async getThem (lessonId) {
      var lesson_info = await this.getPractice(lessonId)
      //console.log("Lesson info:", lesson_info.words_id.split(","))
      var word_info = this.getWordsById(lesson_info.words_id.split(","))
      //console.log("words ", word_info)
      return word_info;
  }
```

Comment: the queries are asynchronous, since you await them, they must be ... so, you'll need to ask a different question

Comment: Doesn't awaiting them force them to be synchronous by definition ?

Comment: @Steve2056726 no.

Comment: no, you can not turn asynchronous function syncrhonous ... the basic laws of time don't allow that ... what async/await does is make the code *look* more synchronous. I think it was meant to make it easy for people who have difficulty dealing with asynchrony, but has resulted in people thinking either it turns asynchronous code synchronous (despite the async) or, that await magically waits for any sort of asynchrony ... not just Promises

Comment: @JaromandaX _the basic laws of time don't allow that_ [oh yes they do](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deasync) ;) I'd never recommend _actually_ using that library, but it _is_ possible if you're willing to take a chainsaw to the Node.js internals.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - that's written in c - so, doesn't count :p

Comment: C++ actually, but point taken. It still makes me cringe seeing how many people use that.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts syncifying is like taking a Formula one car, replacing the wheels with penny farthing wheels, big at the front, little at the back, and wondering not only why you didn't qualify, but why everyone is laughing at you :p

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain the concept with simple code block:

```
const func1 = (num, ms) => new Promise((res, rej) => {
    console.log(`func1 for ${num}`);
    setTimeout(() => { res(`func1 for ${num}`) }, ms);
});

const func2 = (resp, num, ms) => new Promise((res, rej) => {
    console.log(`func2 for ${num}`);
    setTimeout(() => { res(`${resp} func2 for ${num}`) }, ms);
});

async function x() {
    await Promise.all([1, 2, 3, 4].map(async (num) => {
        let resp1 = await func1(num, 5000);
        let resp2 = await func2(resp1, num, 5000);
        console.log(resp2);
    }));
    console.log('Done!!');
}
x();
```

Function x() is the main one, it iterates over array of numbers, which calls func1 asynchronously.
Once func1 resolves, func2 is called using the response of func1, and then it takes its own sweet time to resolve.
Hope it helps.

--- Probable code solution (couldn't test of course) ---

```
async function getWordsById(word_ids) {
    var words = [];
    await Promise.all(word_ids.map(async word_id => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let resp = this.db.collection('words_2').doc(word_id).get();
            words.push(resp.data());
            resolve('');
        });
    }));
    return words;
}

async function getPractice (lessonId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let resp = this.db.collection('practice').doc(lessonId).get();
        resolve(resp.data());
    });
}

async function getThem (lessonId) {
    var lesson_info = await this.getPractice(lessonId)
    var word_info = await this.getWordsById(lesson_info.words_id.split(","))
    return word_info;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The only problem is that in my code the array is returned by  getPractice() so I can't do Promise.all().map([array]) like you've done here

Comment: This was only a sample code block to help you grasp the concepts. You will have to write the code according to your needs. In your case, Promise.all() would be used inside getWordsById() function. Also, you have to await the function getWordsById() inside getThem()

Comment: Would it be possible to put the second db query inside the first queries .then() statement so it executes when the promise resolves? Or is this bad practice?

Comment: Edited answer to have the probable solution, please try

Comment: Realized your get() calls might not be async, so promisified the methods. Try updated code.

Comment: @Chiranjib ... `.get().then` safe to assume `.get()` returns a Promise